# ssh as hidden service - username passed in clear?

Tags: onion-services

I have set up sshd on my box as a hidden service.  I'm wondering if, when I

`torify ssh uname@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion`

is the user-name passed in the clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the username will not pass in the clear. From the moment the SSH client uses Tor via torify/torsocks all data is encrypted.

If you try:

```
torify ssh -vv uname@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion
```

You will see that a connection is established before the username is tried. If you still feel unsafe, use shared SSH keys instead and run SSH on a non-standard port.

Comment: Thanks.  -vv was helpful.  Your other comments are general ssh security, right? 
 I do use keys.  As for the non-standard port, I think I've misunderstood - I had thought that the xxx.onion codes both the machine and port of the service, but I guess not...  So if I want to offer both ssh and http on my server via tor, I will have two HIddenServiceDir's, right?  Meaning two hostnames?  Is it possible to use the same onion address for both?